# Does $k=1$ follow from $I(5^k)+I(m^2) \leq \frac{43}{15}$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p=5$?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)$, and denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $n$, if one exists, must have the form
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.

Here is my *initial* question:

> Does $k=1$ follow from
> $$I(5^k)+I(m^2) \leq \frac{43}{15},$$
> if $I(x)$ is the abundancy index of $x$ and $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p=5$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $n = p^k m^2$ is perfect and $I$ is multiplicative, then we have
$$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)}.$$
But $p \mid p^k$.  In particular, $I(p) \leq I(p^k)$.  This implies that we have the upper bound
$$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} \leq \frac{2}{I(p)} = \frac{2p}{p+1}.$$
In particular, if $p=5$, then we obtain
$$I(m^2) \leq \frac{5}{3}.$$

Hereinafter, we shall assume that $p=5$.

Now, consider the product
$$\bigg(I(p^k) - \frac{5}{3}\bigg)\bigg(I(m^2) - \frac{5}{3}\bigg).$$
It can be proven that $I(p^k) < I(m^2)$.  (For a proof, see [[Dris (2012)]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).)  Thus, this product is nonnegative (since $I(m^2) \leq \frac{5}{3}$), whereupon we get
$$\bigg(I(p^k) - \frac{5}{3}\bigg)\bigg(I(m^2) - \frac{5}{3}\bigg) \geq 0 \implies I(p^k)I(m^2) + \bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)^2 \geq \frac{5}{3}\cdot\bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg)$$
$$\implies 2 + \bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)^2 \geq \frac{5}{3}\cdot\bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg) \implies I(p^k) + I(m^2) \leq \frac{6}{5} + \frac{5}{3} = \frac{43}{15}.$$

Now, we compute an exact expression for
$$I(p^k) + I(m^2) = I(p^k) + \frac{2}{I(p^k)}$$
when $p=5$.  We obtain
$$I(5^k) + \frac{2}{I(5^k)} = \frac{(5^{k+1} - 1)^2 + {32}\cdot{5^{2k}}}{5^k \cdot {4} (5^{k+1} - 1)} = \frac{57 \cdot {5^{2k}} - 2 \cdot {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \cdot {5^{2k+1}} - 4 \cdot {5^k}}.$$

From the same paper cited above, we have the lower bound
$$\frac{57}{20} < I(p^k) + I(m^2)$$
so that collectively we have
$$\frac{57}{20} < I(5^k) + \frac{2}{I(5^k)} = \frac{57 \cdot {5^{2k}} - 2 \cdot {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \cdot {5^{2k+1}} - 4 \cdot {5^k}} \leq \frac{43}{15},$$
from which we obtain the (trivial) lower bound
$$k \geq 1,$$
per this [WolframAlpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%2057%2F20%20%3C%20%28%2857%285%5E%282k%29%29%20-%202%285%5E%28k%2B1%29%29%20%2B%201%29%2F%284%285%5E%282k%2B1%29%29%20-%204%285%5Ek%29%29%29%20%3C%3D%2043%2F15%20for%20k).

Here is my *follow-up* question:

> Why does the condition
> $$I(5^k) + \frac{2}{I(5^k)} \in \bigg(\frac{57}{20},\frac{43}{15}\bigg]$$
> not result in a nontrivial bound for $k$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your follow-up question well, but we have $\frac{d}{dk}(I(5^k)+\frac{2}{I(5^k)})\lt 0,\lim_{k\to \infty}(I(5^k)+\frac{2}{I(5^k)})=\frac{57}{20}$ and $I(5)+\frac{2}{I(5)}=\frac{43}{15}$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I invite you to write out your last comment as an answer to this question, so that I may be able to accept it.

Comment: I've just converted my comment into an answer with some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

I'm not sure if I understand your follow-up question well, but we have

$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dk}\bigg(I(5^k)+\frac{2}{I(5^k)}\bigg)&=-\frac{ 7\cdot 5^{2 k} + 2\cdot 5^{k + 1} - 1}{4\cdot 5^k (5^{k + 1} - 1)^2}\log 5\lt 0
\\\\\lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg(I(5^k)+\frac{2}{I(5^k)}\bigg)&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{57  -\frac{ 2}{5^{k-1}} + \frac{1}{5^{2k}}}{20 - \frac{4}{5^k}}=\frac{57}{20}
\\\\I(5)+\frac{2}{I(5)}&=\frac{57 \cdot {5^{2}} - 2 \cdot {5^{2}} + 1}{4 \cdot {5^{3}} - 4 \cdot {5}}=\frac{43}{15}\end{align}$$

Comment: I apologize @mathlove, but I do not seem to understand how you are getting that
$$\frac{d}{dk}\bigg(I(5^k) + \frac{2}{I(5^k)}\bigg) < 0$$
from your computed expression.  Note that $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Ohh sorry!  I missed the negative sign in front of the fraction!  Gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove.  =)