# On the abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers and a possible upper bound for the special/Euler prime

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This post is an offshoot of this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3754387).)

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)$, and denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $n$, if one exists, must have the form
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.

Here is my *question*:

> Does $p \leq P$ follow from $$I(p^k)+I(m^2) \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{p-1}{p(p+1)}\bigg),$$ if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, where we set
> $$0 < \varepsilon = \frac{p-1}{p(p+1)}$$
> and $P$ is some finite constant?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Notice that the inequality
$$I(p^k)+I(m^2) \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{p-1}{p(p+1)}\bigg)$$
holds in general, since
$$\bigg[I(p^k) - \frac{2p}{p+1}\bigg]\bigg[I(m^2) - \frac{2p}{p+1}\bigg] \geq 0$$
follows from
$$I(p^k) < I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} \leq \frac{2}{I(p)} = \frac{2p}{p+1}.$$

Furthermore, note that we obtain the upper bound
$$\varepsilon = \frac{p-1}{p(p+1)} = \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{p+1}\bigg) < \frac{1}{p + 1} \leq \frac{1}{6},$$
since $p$ is prime with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $p \geq 5$.

We now compute for $p$ in terms of $\varepsilon$:

$$\varepsilon p^2 + p(\varepsilon - 1) + 1 = 0$$
$$p = \frac{(1-\varepsilon) \pm \sqrt{(1-\varepsilon)^2 - 4\varepsilon}}{2\varepsilon}$$

This gives
$$p = \frac{(1-\varepsilon) \pm \sqrt{{\varepsilon}^2 - 6\varepsilon + 1}}{2\varepsilon}.$$

> Quoting verbatim from [[Remark 11, page 5 of The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers by Dris (JIS, 2012)]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf):
> *Remark 11*.  As remarked by Joshua Zelinsky in 2005: "Any improvement on the upper bound of $3$ would have (similar) implications for all arbitrarily large primes and thus would be a very major result."  (e.g. $L(p) < 2.99$ implies $p \leq 97$.)  In this sense, the inequality
> $$\frac{57}{20} < I(p^k) + I(m^2) < 3$$
> is best-possible.

I tried using WolframAlpha to get the global maxima of the two functions
$$p(\varepsilon_1) = \frac{(1-\varepsilon_1) + \sqrt{{\varepsilon_1}^2 - 6{\varepsilon_1} + 1}}{2\varepsilon_1}$$
and
$$p(\varepsilon_2) = \frac{(1-\varepsilon_2) - \sqrt{{\varepsilon_2}^2 - 6{\varepsilon_2} + 1}}{2\varepsilon_2},$$
but the outputs were not helpful.

Alas, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: It seems to me that you are basically asking if it is true that if $\frac{p-1}{p(p+1)}\gt 0$ with $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then there is a constant $P$ such that $p\le P$, which is false since $\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{p-1}{p(p+1)}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove.  Please see the details in the hyperlinked JIS paper, particularly Zelinsky's remark from 2005.  Nonetheless, surely you agree that
$$\frac{p-1}{p(p+1)} > 0$$
for *each* prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Comment: Although I'm not sure if I understand the core of your question, I'll write what I've got. (1) There is no $\varepsilon_2$ such that $p(\varepsilon_2)\ge 5$ and $0\lt \varepsilon_2\le\frac 16$. (2) $p(\varepsilon_1)\ge 5$ and $0\lt \varepsilon_1\le\frac 16\iff 0\lt \varepsilon_1\le\frac{2}{15}$. (3) $\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon_1\to 0^+}p(\varepsilon_1)=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again, @mathlove!  I invite you to write out your last comment as an answer to this question, so that I may be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer proves the following three claims :

**Claim 1** : There is no $x$ such that $\dfrac{1-x - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\ $ and $\ 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16$

**Claim 2** : $\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\ $ and $\ 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16\iff 0\lt x\le \dfrac{2}{15}$

**Claim 3** : $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}=+\infty$

Note that $$x^2 - 6x + 1\ge 0\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le\frac 16\iff 0\lt x\le \frac 16$$

---

**Claim 1** : There is no $x$ such that $\dfrac{1-x - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\ $ and $\ 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16$

*Proof* :

Suppose that there is such an $x$. Then, we have
$$\begin{align}&\frac{1-x - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16
\\\\&\implies \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}\le 1-11x\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16
\\\\&\implies\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}\le 1-11x\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le 1-11x
\\\\&\implies x^2 - 6x + 1\le (1-11x)^2\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 1{11}
\\\\&\implies x\ge\frac{2}{15}\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 1{11}\end{align}$$
which is impossible.

---

**Claim 2** : $\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\ $ and $\ 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16\iff 0\lt x\le \dfrac{2}{15}$

*Proof* :

$$\begin{align}&\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\ge 5\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16
\\\\&\iff \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}\ge 11x-1\quad\text{and}\quad 0\lt x\le \dfrac 16
\\\\&\iff 0\lt x\le\frac{1}{11}\quad\text{or}\quad\bigg(x^2-6x+1\ge (11x-1)^2\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{11}\lt x\le\frac 16\bigg)
\\\\&\iff 0\lt x\le\frac{1}{11}\quad\text{or}\quad\bigg(0\le x\le\frac{2}{15}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{11}\lt x\le\frac 16\bigg)
\\\\&\iff 0\lt x\le\frac{1}{11}\quad\text{or}\quad\frac{1}{11}\lt x\le\frac{2}{15}
\\\\&\iff 0\lt x\le\frac{2}{15}\end{align}$$

---

**Claim 3** : $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}=+\infty$

*Proof* : Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1})=2$, we get
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{1-x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}=+\infty$$